# Django Can't recreate Database table?

Tags: django, database, phpmyadmin

Unfortunately I deleted two database table from my phpmyadmin database, I deleted migration file from corresponding app, and run this two command

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_name
python manage.py migrate
```

But still cant recreate my database table. how to fix this issue?

Comment: you should look at the `django_migrations` table, and remove the entries of the migration that was applied previously. But I *strongly* advise not to manually remove tables, it usually only generates more trouble.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I would say it is better to use the [--fake flag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake) rather than manually editing the migration table. Noyon if this is not prod I guess easiest would be to drop the database, else you would probably have some backup to recover to right?